# How to know the flattening factor for a ellipse?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, conic-sections

I want to know how can I get the flattening factor for a ellipse by knowing its semi-major and semi-minor axes ?

Actually I tried this formula:

> $f=\left(\frac{a}{b}-1\right)$

While $f$ is the flattening factor, $a is the semi\,major\,axes$, $b is the semi\,minor\,axes$.
**I think it's true because when I try it with circle it gives me $\left(\,f=0.0\,0\right)$**. but I don't have any source for this formula and I'm not sure if it's true !

**So if any one know what is the exact formula for finding the flattening factor for a ellipse ?**

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) gives the flattening factor as $1-\frac ba$, which would be zero for a circle.  That shouldn't be surprising, as a circle isn't flattened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *flattening factor* is given by $\;f = 1 - \cfrac ba$.

A closely related term you might be interested in is the **eccentricity** of an ***[ellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse)***, usually denoted $e$ or $\varepsilon$. Eccentricity in general represents ratio of the distance between the two foci, $2h$, to the length of the major axis, $2a$: $$e = \dfrac{2h}{2a} = \dfrac ha$$

where the distance between a focus and the center is given by $\;h = \sqrt{a^2-b^2}.$

In fact, we can represent eccentricity in terms of $a, b$: 
$$e=\varepsilon=\sqrt{\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2}} =\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2} = \frac ha$$

For an ellipse, the eccentricity is $0 < e < 1$. Eccentricity is zero when the foci coincide with the center point, i.e, the figure is a circle. As eccentricity increases, the shape gets more elongated (stretched/flattened): the closer to $1$ it gets, the flatter the ellipse.

Comment: The OP is using $f=1-\frac ba$ as the flattening, and you are using $f=ae$. This might be a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome, Mohammad!

Comment: @amWhy: Due to grammar and formatting ugliness, I edited my post today about six times. I hate doing it, but I'd rather it be correct than deal with the ambiguities of how bumping works.

Comment: Hello, @Babak! $\large \overset{\small\star\star}{\smile}$

Comment: @Babak Yes, I did! How are you doing this fine day?